# Cross-Compiling kernel can't find gcc

Tags: raspberry-pi, make, gcc, raspbian, arm

I am cross compiling the Raspbian kernel since it will take about 12 hours for the Pi to do (Raspberry Pi 1).

I have the build tools for ARM and the kernel in two separate folders in `/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/`.

I am following this guide: [Raspberry Pi Kernel Compilation - eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation)

My issue is that when I go to compile, it can't find arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3 which is clearly in the folder I linked when I did export CCPREFIX. Here is what I did:

```
gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ export CCPREFIX=/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

And it returns when I try to build:

```
gray@Rava-Xubuntu:~/Desktop/tmp/linux$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: 1: /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3: not found
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: 1: /home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3: not found
Kbuild:43: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
Makefile:990: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Even though the file is clearly in there:

[image: Even though the file is clearly in there]

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin` to PATH: `export PATH=/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Same result. :(

Comment: This is strange. Either there is a typo somewhere in this long path, or you'd hit a bug. For me alien kernel compilation always worked as `make ARCH=arch CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/toolchain/bin/toolchain-triplet-`. Double check everything, and if still no go, try `strace -f -eexecve -v -s150 -o log make ...` and then post result (file `log`) on pastebin.com.

Comment: Is the toolchain complete? You seem not to be able to compile an asm file, not a C file.

Comment: I had to truncate it a bit @siblynx

http://pastebin.com/ZdGfP3Qg

That is the last bit of the log.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.

I just grabbed the crossbuild version of gcc (I think that is what it is)

```
sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

And then my new path is:

```
export CCPREFIX=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

And the build works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I did not able to find where `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3` is failing from your provided http://pastebin.com/ZdGfP3Qg, but your PATH environment variable contains weird characters:

`PATH=/home/gray/Desktop/tmp/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-ras\342\200\214\342\200\213pbian/bin:/home/gray/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbi" ...`

Those `\342\200\214\342\200\213` in `raspbian` part should not be there.

Recheck your scripts and set PATH appropriately.

Your CROSS_COMPILE however appears to be intact. Most probably gcc tries to run things from PATH or you have a broken toolchain/dangling symlink somewhere.

Use this strace to debug deeply:

`strace -f -v -s150 -o log -eexecve,stat,stat64 (make command)` and then do `fgrep ENOENT log`. Then filter out nonexistent items from your PATH and try to locate and fix remaining items to be on place.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to dig through the log and see it was looking for files in a lot of different places. I posted my solution.

Comment: Nice. So next time using distro provided items is more helpful than messing with own ones. Except the cases when you need your own setup. But in that cases you're already know what to do :-)